# Adding touch controls to character controller? Unity2d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch, controls

Got this simple character controller that moves my platformer character left and right with a flip.

Was hoping someone could integrate or show me how to add in touch controls for android/ios.

Just a simple touch left side of screen to go left and right side to go right.

Thanks

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RobotController : MonoBehaviour {
//This will be our maximum speed as we will always be multiplying by 1
public float maxSpeed = 2f;
//a boolean value to represent whether we are facing left or not
bool facingRight = false;
//a value to represent our Animator
Animator anim;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //set anim to our animator
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {

    float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");//Gives us of one if we are moving via the arrow keys
    //move our Players rigidbody
    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    //set our speed
    anim.SetFloat ("Speed",Mathf.Abs (move));
    //if we are moving left but not facing left flip, and vice versa
    if (move < 0 && !facingRight) {

        Flip ();
    } else if (move > 0 && facingRight) {
        Flip ();
    }
}

//flip if needed
void Flip(){
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Update() method, you'll want to use a foreach loop which loops through all the touch events in that particular frame update.

```
foreach(Touch touch in Input.touches)
{
    if(leftButton.HitTest(touch.position))
    {
        //move character left
    }

    if(rightButton.HitTest(touch.position))
    {
        //move character right
    }
}
```

This assumes that you're setting up two GUITexture buttons for your left and right controls in the start() method.

Comment: Rahin, thanks for the response.  So can i made like two huge transparent buttons on each side of the screen, how do I link your code to those objects?